# How can I rotate my camera around the Y axis on a specific orientation without rotating the x and z axis?

Tags: opengl, glm-math

I am trying to rotate my camera from it's position but around the Y axis. If anyone has any ideas 
please let me know. Whenever I use the glm rotate function I am faced with this issue in it's third 
parameter.

```
glm::mat4 xlook(1.0f);
glm::vec3 position(0.05f, 0.05f, -1.0f);
glm::vec3 viewdirection(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glm::vec3 UP(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
xlook = glm::rotate(xlook, leftright, UP);
glm::mat3 rot = glm::mat3(xlook);
viewdirection = rot * viewdirection;
glm::mat4 views;
glm::mat4 trans1(1.0f);
trans1 = glm::rotate(trans1, 0.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
trans1 = glm::rotate(trans1, 0.0f, glm::vec3(4.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
trans1 = glm::scale(trans1, glm::vec3(Thescale,Thescale, 0.0f));
trans1 = glm::translate(trans1, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, Thetranslation));
views = glm::lookAt(position, position + viewdirection, UP);
```

Comment: I have this code from an opengl course I was following, might help you (the OrbitCamera class does rotate around Y axis, its triggered by mouse movement, which you can find its usage in the PhongScene class in the same repo)
https://github.com/aymanmh/basicopengl/blob/master/basicopengl/Src/Camera.cpp

Comment: @aiman09 Thank you very much.

Comment: @Rabbid76 What should I do?